# Movie player to play unrared .rar files

Tags: bittorrent, media

I have a ubuntu server with transmission set up. I download most of my movies and series in .rar format. I have to unrar the movie and then look at it. Do anyone know about a movie player who can play .rar files? I know xbmc can, but xbmc is pretty resource heavy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vlc can do it. Just open first part and it will do the rest.

[Source](http://www.unixmen.com/22-things-you-can-do-with-vlc/)

Answer (score 2):

PS3 media server can also play rar'd files. It can browse rar files and play the contents within them without having to extract them.

Also you don't need a PS3 to stream with it. It will stream to many devices. I use it to stream to a Samsung AllShare TV. Even Banshee picks it up so you can watch the movies locally if you choose.

You can see the option here in this screenshot

[image]

From [help.ubuntu.com/community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ps3MediaServer) to install run the following commands in terminal, one line at a time -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:happy-neko/ps3mediaserver
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ps3mediaserver
```

For more information, http://www.ps3mediaserver.org/about/